# A space $X$ where $X$ minus a point is homotopically trivial, but $X$ isn't

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

An example of a space $X$ that is not homotopy equivalent to a point, but there exists a $p \in X$ such that $X \backslash \{p\}$ is homotopy equivalent to a point.

Comment: Two points works

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** How about $S^1$? Not "homotopy equivalent to a point" you have via the fundamental group $\pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$ for example, so now what about the complement of a point? At least intuitively it should be clear why this example works.